# Как правильно изучать QML?

Tags: qtcreator, qml

Я изучаю QML и для примера решил разобрать одно open-source приложение. Проблема в том, что там больше ста файлом .qml ...

Существует ли какое-то приложение, где можно получить наследование между файлами в виде, например, графика?
Или же придётся руками перебирать файл за файлом, записывая результаты исследований на листочке.

Концепцию QML я понял, но хотелось бы создать *карту* этих файлов. Программа написана в QtCreator, может быть в нем есть подобная функция?

Comment: а как должна выглядеть эта карта? возможно, в некоторых случаях Вашу задачу можно решить простым grep+graphviz

Comment: @KoVadim, под картой я подразумевал простую иллюстрацию с минимальным описанием. Конечно хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс (не только связи но и переменные, функции и тд.), если есть такие программы. Но думаю, подошло бы и что-то попроще. Главное получить в итоге наглядное "древо", при осмотре которого не составило бы труда его воссоздать или модернизировать.
UPDATE: глянул graphviz, именно так я и представлял. Только насколько я понял придётся составлять вручную.

Comment: Вы написали кучу слов, но не написали самого главного - что именно там должно отображаться

Comment: @KoVadim, id, category, anchors, Rectangle минимум. Задача: узнать что/как/на чем строится слой за слоем

Comment: думаю можно, правда придется писать свой парсер. Но мне кажется, что для большого проекта это будет перегруженная страница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует очень удобное приложение с интерфейсом, позволяющее посмотреть дерево элементов вашего приложение, называется GammaRay (https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/)